# Get nginx to always load /webdir/page.php on directories if no index.html page

Tags: nginx, directoryindex

So i'v been trying out some of the config options in http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule with no luck so far.

What I want is, if someone goes to '10.10.10.1/test/' that it loads the file '/webdir/page.php' (not to redirect them, but to keep them at '10.10.10.1/test/', but load the php page.

I don't really want to re-compile with http://github.com/blueyed/nginx-fancyindex#example since it isn't really what im after, I want to build my own custom directory index in php.

I had this working on Apache way back... but I'v long migrated to lightTPD and now i'v just moved to nginx :)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location /test/ {
  error_page 404 = /webdir/page.php;
  return 404;
}
```

Comment: I don't get 404 errors when I load a folder though, i get a 403, I changed it to 403 which does work... but I also block some users which also return 403 (if I am a blocked user) so I want to display a custom error to the blocked user as well, but not with PHP.

Comment: Hold on, nobody should be blocked. The error_page directive sets custom error page handler for /test/... only. "=" means drop the (404) status. return 404 triggers the handler. 403 should not pop up ever. What's your nginx version?

Comment: Oh I see, I interpreted it wrong. It works now, (with 404) but it still loads the page.php even when a proper page like test.html is selected.

Comment: You mean 10.10.10.1/test/test.html ? Ok, to load /webdir/page.php _just_ for /test/, replace "location /test/" with "location = /test/". To match all the requests for directories (ending with /), "location ~ /$". If nginx hosts files all by itself (no proxying to apache), there're other ways to solve it.

Comment: Ah yes, that works "location ~ /$ { error_page 404 = /page.php; return 404; }" for all dir's and not for valid html/php pages (this is what I wanted), just one last error, it still loads a '403 Forbidden' error when I visit http://10.10.10.10/ (it has a trailing slash so it should work, no?)

Comment: what's in nginx error log?

Comment: "[error] 2098#0: *1 directory index of "/var/www/" is forbidden, client: 10.10.10.2, server: 10.10.10.1, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "10.10.10.1"

Comment: So you must have "location /" declared then. Literal locations checked first, then regular expressions during lookup. A quick fix is to add error_page 403 = /webdir/page.php into "location /"

Comment: that kinda brings me back to my original workaround of using 403, but I found out that chaining the "location /" to "location ~ /" still does what I need it to and then allows my other match to work proper :) Thanks so much for sticking with me to solve this problem.